# Unable to send or receive emails using VPS

Tags: email, email-server

I've installed ISPConfig 3 on my VPS using the brilliant tutorial here: http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=56541

However, if I go to send an email to an account I've set up on the server I get the following error:

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>   michael@gravex.co.uk
>
> Technical details of permanent failure: DNS Error: DNS server returned
>   answer with no data

I've checked my DNS records for that domain, and they are as follows:

```
setanta A       80.xx.xx.xx 
mail.gravex.co.uk   MX  10  80.xx.xx.xx
NS      ns1.6sync.net.  
NS      ns2.6sync.net.  
NS      ns3.6sync.net.  
ftp A       80.xx.xx.xx
mail    A       80.xx.xx.xx
dail    A       80.xx.xx.xx
www A       80.xx.xx.xx
.   A       80.xx.xx.xx
```

I've also tried to send an email from squirrelmail. I've had no errors come back but I've not had the e-mail come through either.

I'm not sure what's going on, as I thought adding mail.gravex.co.uk as an MX record would work, but I don't think it has. What do I need to do to make it work?

Cheers!

**EDIT**
I've changed the MX record so `gravex.co.uk` points to `mail.gravex.co.uk`. However, e-mails still can't be delivered to the account due to the same error.

Also, the DNS server is handled by 6sync, not ISPConfig 3.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@D_Bye is correct; you want to specify the MX record for gravex.co.uk **not** for mail.gravex.co.uk. A fully qualified domain name in a zone needs a dot after it. Also, MX records must point to domain names, not IP addresses, so:

```
gravex.co.uk.  IN  MX  10 mail.gravex.co.uk.
```

---

EDIT:

Just noticed that you're missing `IN` in each line:

```
setanta IN A       80.xx.xx.xx 
mail.gravex.co.uk. IN MX  10  80.xx.xx.xx
gravex.co.uk. IN NS ns1.6sync.net.  
gravex.co.uk. IN NS      ns2.6sync.net.  
gravex.co.uk. IN NS      ns3.6sync.net.  
ftp IN A       80.xx.xx.xx
mail IN A       80.xx.xx.xx
dail IN A       80.xx.xx.xx
www IN A       80.xx.xx.xx
gravex.co.uk. IN   A       80.xx.xx.xx
```

---

EDIT 2:

It's now just occurred to me that you pasted the output of a GUI you're using to edit the DNS record, not the record itself (because there are other parts missing). If this is the case, then setting the MX for gravex.co.uk to mail.gravex.co.uk should solve your problem.

Comment: Still no joy unfortunately!

Comment: Using `dig gravex.co.uk MX` I see no MX records. Either it's still not right, or it may take a little longer to propagate. Are you able to edit the zone file directly or are you using a GUI? A paste of the whole zone file, or a screenshot of the GUI would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the `mail.gravex.co.uk` from the MX entry - with it there, you tell the DNS how to handle mail for `<user>@mail.gravex.co.uk`, instead of `<user>@gravex.co.uk`.

Comment: I've changed it from `mail.gravex.co.uk` to `gravex.co.uk`, and changed the destination to go to `mail.gravex.co.uk`. Or should I just leave it as the IP?

Comment: See nobody's answer - try the format suggested there. It's been a while since I edited a zone file, so my knowledge of the syntax is evidently a little rusty!

Comment: Assuming you're using the ISPConfig GUI, and that it handles the important details (trailing dots, IN, etc.) you should be done -- setting the destination to a domain name is correct.

Comment: I'm not using ISPConfig for DNS, I'm using 6sync.net's servers